# Issue putting Image next to text (not float issue)

Tags: html, css

I tried everything with `CSS` and `HTML` about this. Here's an Image explaining visually what I want to do and what is happening
Tried Margin, Pudding, Clear, Vertical Align and even more. I'm just too tired now of fixing this bug. I tried to fix it for about a day now.

[image]

By the way sorry for my probably bad post, pretty new to this website.

```css
.Intro_IMG {
    max-width: 192px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-align: middle;
}
.Intro{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    margin-top: 48px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="Intro">
    <img class="Intro_IMG" src="https://placehold.it/192x192">
    <h3>Hey bien salut tout le monde c'est Sirius B !</h3>
    <p>Et vous vous trouvez ici sur mon site / projet HTML !</p>
    <p>Ce site est à la base là juste pour que je joue et apprenne l'HTML !</p>
    <p>Donc ici il y aura des trucs un peu random dans ce site car je peux.</p>
    <p>Sinon eh bien ce site sert un peu à rien donc... Ouais.</p>
</div>
```

Someone told me to show the whole code so there it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Accueil</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ArchUI_Light.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="ressources/siriusblogo.png">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Navigation Bar-->
        <nav class="NavBar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="accueil_dark.html">Accueil (Dark)</a> <a href="redirect/discord_light.html">Serveur Discord</a> <a href="redirect/youtube_light.html">Chaîne Youtube</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!--Main Title-->
        <img class="ML" src="ressources/siriusblogo.png">
        <h1>Le Site de Sirius B !</h1>
        <!--WIP Website Message-->
        <div class="WIP_MSG">
            <h2 class="Warning">Veuillez Notez !</h2>
            <p>Ce site est actuellement en développement.</p>
            <p>Il se peut que le site est moche remplis de bugs.</p>
            <p>Merci de votre compréhension.</p>
            <p>- Sirius B</p>
        </div>
        <!--Introduction-->
        <div class="Intro">
                <img class="Intro_IMG" src="https://placehold.it/192x192">
                <h3>Hey bien salut tout le monde c'est Sirius B !</h3>
                <p>Et vous vous trouvez ici sur mon site / projet HTML !</p>
                <p>Ce site est à la base là juste pour que je joue et apprenne l'HTML !</p>
                <p>Donc ici il y aura des trucs un peu random dans ce site car je peux.</p>
                <p>Sinon eh bien ce site sert un peu à rien donc... Ouais.</p>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        <!--Other Info-->
    </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    color: black;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.NavBar {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border: solid #f9f9f9;
    border-width: 10px;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
}
.ML {
    max-width: 96px;
    margin-top: 48px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.ML_Borderless {
    max-width: 96px;
    margin-top: 48px;
}
.ML_Borderless-small {
    max-width: 48px;
    margin-top: 48px;
}
.Warning {
    color: red;
}
.Intro_IMG {
    max-width: 192px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-align: middle;
    margin-right: 12px;
}
.Intro{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    margin-top: 48px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: With the Run Code Snippet it works like I wanted but on my website it just doesn't. Strange.

Comment: Your code is working fine as you expect... check here https://codepen.io/krish4u/pen/mdyoXOM

Comment: The code is fine.. that HTML code is inside an other HTML code ? or is it all what you have ?

Comment: it dosen't, the DIV (Image, Text) is not centered but at least the image is good to go. However the border is way too long. I want it to start 1px on the left of my image, then stops after 1px on the right of the text. Sorry if I badly explained.

Comment: The HTML code shown is inside of an other HTML code

Comment: Okay, Can you show the whole code then ?

Comment: TaouBen, Done you can see it now.

Comment: Hi, Again, so Yeah, what you see is because you have text-align: center in the parent Node which is the body in your case.

Comment: So i need to do text-align: left; for my text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Taou Ben's code for a while but then I found a way simplier solution.
Just use the following CSS and HTML:

```css
.IntroDIV {
    max-width: 768px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    margin-top: 48px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}

.Intro_IMG {
    max-width: 192px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
        <div class="IntroDIV">
                <div class="Intro_IMGDIV">
                 <img class="Intro_IMG" src="https://via.placeholder.com/512/">
                </div>        
                <div>
                  <h3>Hey bien salut tout le monde c'est Sirius B !</h3>
                  <p>Et vous vous trouvez ici sur mon site / projet HTML !</p>
                  <p>Ce site est à la base là juste pour que je joue et apprenne l'HTML !</p>
                  <p>Donc ici il y aura des trucs un peu random dans ce site car je peux.</p>
                  <p>Sinon eh bien ce site sert un peu à rien donc... Ouais.</p>
                </div>     
              </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to change your HTML structure and CSS a little bit.

Change `.Intro` display to `inline-block` with `width: auto`. Then append a `div` inside `.Intro` with `clear: both` just in case if your text height is smaller than the image. After then, put your text content inside another div to control its width and height.

```css
.Intro_IMG {
    max-width: 192px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-align: middle;
    margin-right: 12px;
}
.Intro{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    margin-top: 48px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
}
.Intro_Content {
  max-height: 192px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="Intro">
    <img class="Intro_IMG" src="https://placehold.it/192x192">
    <div class="Intro_Content">
      <h3>Hey bien salut tout le monde c'est Sirius B !</h3>
      <p>Et vous vous trouvez ici sur mon site / projet HTML !</p>
      <p>Ce site est à la base là juste pour que je joue et apprenne l'HTML !</p>
      <p>Donc ici il y aura des trucs un peu random dans ce site car je peux.</p>
      <p>Sinon eh bien ce site sert un peu à rien donc... Ouais.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it kinda works. The only issue now on your code that you proposed is that the text is not properly aligned with the Image, I want it next to the Image, not under.

Comment: No need to all of this to fix his problem I guess! David

Comment: No David, when you add overflow: hidden and max-height: 192px, then he won't be able to see the content of his paragraph if it is a big text.

Comment: That's why my first anwser didn't have it but OP wants the height to be exactly the same as the image, I can't see too many options left than forcing height, change text size or putting all text after `h3` inside one paragraph and then using `text-overflow: ellipsis;`.

Answer (score 2):

This is an edited answer, so here is the code I think it will work for you!

Make a change in your HTML structure :

```
<body style="text-align:center;">
  <div class="Intro clear-fix">
    <div class="img-container">
     <img class="Intro_IMG" src="https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2@1.5x.png">

    </div>        
    <div class="content-container">
      <h3>Hey bien salut tout le monde c'est Sirius B !</h3>
      <p>Et vous vous trouvez ici sur mon site / projet HTML !</p>
      <p>Ce site est à la base là juste pour que je joue et apprenne l'HTML !</p>
      <p>Donc ici il y aura des trucs un peu random dans ce site car je peux.</p>
      <p>Sinon eh bien ce site sert un peu à rien donc... Ouais.</p>
    </div>     
  </div>
</body>
```

And this is your new CSS :

```
.Intro_IMG {
    max-width: 192px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-align: middle;
}

.Intro{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    margin-top: 48px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.img-container, .content-container {
  float: left;
}

.content-container {
  text-align: left;
}

.clear-fix {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Well that went well https://imgur.com/a/bDC2C0Z The border is like way too long now.

Comment: Check the image. It doesn't still work like I want, David's Solution kinda works, the only issue is that well... The text is getting under the image. And I don't want that.

Comment: So for me! you need to change the HTML code to get what you want to get! you put the img inside a div, and the rest in another div, and add float:left to both of them, and text-align:left to the second one!

Comment: But then how do I center both divs ? (I putted a DIV (image) with the DIV (text) inside to test it.) Now how do I center it? The image and text is perfect. Just need to center that thing

Comment: just try to add a max-width of 800px or 700px ( play number ) to you div with Intro class

Comment: I splited it into three divs and idk which one it is Intro = Intro_IMG and Intro_TEXT | Intro_TEXT = DIV with the text only | Intro_IMG = Intro with only the image. Tried the INTRO thing and it did nothing

Comment: What ? add a max-width to the parent, I mean .Intro { ...oldcode, max-width: 800px; }

Comment: it is impossible, I tried the code myself, I will edit my answer to give the full code, just wait

Comment: Check the answer now, .. I thin the max-width is not needed, but tried the code myself and it is working

Answer (score 0):

Put the image in a div and the texts in another div. The main container will have two divs, first one containing image and the second one containing texts.
Set the display of the main container to flex. Set align-items to center.

Comment: Too bad you are too late but this seems as a valuable and easier solution. Ill be sure to try out ! When I can.

Comment: lol. do it next time. the float based styling is not that efficient anyway.